# Symfony2 redirect is doing a forward

Tags: symfony

When I redirect to a different route, the url is staying the same. The redirect() function is acting like the forward().

Controller 1 :

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/foo", name="default_foo")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function fooAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = new Table();
    $entity->setField('test');
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('default_bar'));
}
```

Controller 2:

```
/**
 * testing
 *
 * @Route("/bar", name="default_bar")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function barAction(Request $request)
{
    return new Response('<html>Hello from bar</html>');
}
```

routing.yml:

```
Acme_pl:
    resource: "@AcmePlBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix:   /


fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

The url is always mydomain.com/default/foo even after forwarding to bar.
When I refresh, controller foo is being called again and a new record is being inserted in db.

Any ideas ?

Comment: My guess is that the router matches `/test` before `/test2`, hence you're getting a new row inserted. Try renaming `/test2` to `/foobar` and see what happens

Comment: Would also guess like @Touki. With annotations it's relative unclear to determine the routes order, which is important.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. Actually it's doing the same in my whole application.

Comment: test2Action() is being executed. It's just the url is wrong. So I don't think it's a routing issue.

Comment: Can you try with `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('...'), 301)` ?

Comment: Same results with 301.

Comment: What do you have in `routing.yml` or `routing.php` for **default_bar** ?

Comment: I just added routing.yml to my question.

Comment: The solution was to generate an absolute url with $this->generateUrl('default_foo', array(), true). Relative urls would not work neither with $this->redirect nor with header('Location: '.$this->generateUrl('default_foo')). Both will not show the url redirected to but rather keeps the same url in the browser's address bar. No idea why!

Comment: So this is not a Symfony question. I don't know if I should delete the question or what...